# scrollTop jquery, scrolling to div not scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, scroll, scrolltop

I came across this code on codepad: https://codepad.co/snippet/YPDXE33r

However on my website, when I click the button, the page moves down about 1cm and not to the appropriate div?

I have added all of the code below and it works on the example above.

This code is being used on a wordpress site.

Thanks

HTML

```
<section>
<a href="#" class="scroll-down" address="true"></a>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.scroll-down {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
  transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
}

.scroll-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  background-size: 14px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

.scroll-down:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 8px);
    left: calc(50% - 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    content: "";
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-width: 0px 0 2px 2px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  100%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('.scroll-down').click (function() {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#div_outerfooter').offset().top }, 'slow');
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please create [mcve], as it is, this could be caused by anything. Without working example it's anybodys guess.

Comment: Well no, we don't have any idea if you don't share the full relevant code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: Your example still is not complete, the html does not have an element with id "div_outerfooter". So the example does not help to debug your code.

Comment: The id div_outerfooter is within the entire code on my page.

Comment: is there any error message in the console log?

Answer (score 0):

Try it some time working inside of document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".scroll-down").click (function() {
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('section.ok').offset().top }, 'slow');
          return false;
        });
     });
```